# How to add custom message in Highchart's printed image?

Tags: jquery, highcharts

basically i want that the image that is exported by Highchart should display some custom message along with the chart

Comment: This would require some amount of code I believe. Got any?

Comment: Nope ..  I tried a lot but could not find a workaround

Comment: Add code because anybody won't help you here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two options, both are based on `load` event.

One is to check `chart.options.chart.forExport` flag. When flag is set to `true`, then add extra elements on the chart using `chart.renderer`. See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2631uf45/) and more info about the [Renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer).

Second option, is to do the same, but in [`exporting.chartOptions.chart.events.load`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting.chartOptions) callback. That callback is used only when exporting chart.

Comment: can we also add some custom images at header or footer of chart using html img tag ?

Comment: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.image  . I think this can be done using this Renderer.image   .

Comment: Yes, use `renderer.image()` to add images to the chart.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your own custom message something like this.

Take an example

```
series: [{
        type: 'area',
        name: 'your own custom message',
        pointInterval: 365 * 24 * 3600000,
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2015, 0, 1),
        data:[1,2,3]
    }]
```

The custom message will be prompted on pointing to the graph by mouse(arrow).
In the name field you can have your own message. This field is optional, even if you remove this field highchart generate its own message.It wont give any error.